# NHibernate and MySql Keywords

Tags: mysql, nhibernate, hql

Why Nibernate HQL can not handle the following query:

```
from Deal D where (D.ApprovalDate + INTERVAL 1 Year) < current_timestamp() <  (D.RenewalDate + INTERVAL -1 Year)
```

knowing that INTERVAL and YEAR are keywords in MySQL, so this is kind of mixing Sql within Hql (unless Hql can handle date functions like so and I don't know) . The dialect is **MySQLDialect**

Its perfectly valid to execute this query

```
  SELECT '2005-01-01' + INTERVAL 1 Year;
```

Comment: Do u want to use hql or sql? pardon me, If I didn't understand some thing of this, but are you intentionally using sql in hql ? I am not sure if u can do that

Comment: you're using the correct dialect? for instance MySQL5Dialect

Comment: I believe you can, HQL should pass any non-translated string down to database engine to figure it ... At least that's what the documentation says

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the Sql directly in the query using Criteria Query. Something like this

```
Session.CreateCriteria<Deal>()
.Add(Restrictions.Sql(D.ApprovalDate + " INTERVAL 1 Year < current_timestamp() < " + D.RenewalDate + " INTERVAL -1 Year")
```

The Restrictions.Sql will pass whatever you give it directly to the database as sql.

Comment: Thanks for this proposal, but I'm building HQL query dynamically. I will look into this solution, but do you think there is something powerful that works with hql, any ideas ?

Comment: I'm curious your reason to choose HQL over the Criteria. Criteria Queries compile down to HQL so it may be possible to do what you are trying but I have never figured out how. I had similar issues needing to pass Sql directly and ended up using Criteria. Are you forced to use HQL?

Comment: Well, no! But If that melts down to hql, I wonder how that hql looks like :) ... Thanks again for your tremendous efforts

Comment: Np, I'm digging through the NHibernate source code now to see if it is possible using HQL. I'll update you if I find a way. Hopefully the Criteria way can help you until then.

Comment: It did help. I hope you get good results with hql ... good luck